# File access system api(wicg-file-system-access) is not loading in dev environment

Tags: angular, file-system-access-api

I am using wicg-file-system-access to access local files for my angular application, it works correctly on localhost but when i deploy changes to dev environment it is not working, i see window.showSaveFilePicker is undefined.

Is there any configuration that required for deployed site?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [you need](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#ref-for-dom-window-showsavefilepicker) a [[SecureContext]](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#SecureContext) (https:// or localhost).

```
[SecureContext] // <-- This means it's only exposed in secure contexts
partial interface Window {
    Promise<sequence<FileSystemFileHandle>> showOpenFilePicker(optional OpenFilePickerOptions options = {});
    Promise<FileSystemFileHandle> showSaveFilePicker(optional SaveFilePickerOptions options = {});
    Promise<FileSystemDirectoryHandle> showDirectoryPicker(optional DirectoryPickerOptions options = {});
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that chrome shows "your connection to this site is not secure", i tried with other site it works fine there

Comment: You also have a `globalThis.isSecureContext` property available that let's you check quickly if your current context is secure.